# How to set quill editor as a required form field?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, quill

I'm using the ngx-quill editor in my angular application. I want to ensure that this form field is filled in prior to submitting the form. When I try adding in

```
[require]="true"
```

...and test this by submitting an empty field, the control is showing that it's still 'valid'.

Here is the html snippet:

```
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <quill-editor #quill="ngModel" [style]="{height: '420px'}" [(ngModel)]="blogPost.content" name="content" [minLength]="1"
      [required]="true"></quill-editor>
  </div>
```

Comment: How do you read the value of the quill editor? It is possible if you read the editor with for example a .html() in the ts files, that you get a `<p><br></p>` as a response.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use "required" instead of [require]="true"

so you have to change the code like this:

```
 <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
<quill-editor #quill="ngModel" [style]="{height: '420px'}" [(ngModel)]="blogPost.content" name="content" [minLength]="1"
  required></quill-editor>
```